# railscast 197 : error when trying to add fields with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

HI,

I tried to follow the 197: Nested Model Form Part 2 [railscast 197](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) but i have this error when i try to add the field by javascript :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &
```

Here the helper :

```
  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)  
    new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new  
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|  
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)  
    end  
    link_to_function(name, h("add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")"))  
  end
```

And the javascript function :

```
function add_fields(link, association, content) {  
  var new_id = new Date().getTime();  
  var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g");  
  $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));  
}
```

The call in my view :

```
- form_for @report do |f|
  %h1= f.label :name 
  %p= f.text_field :name
  - f.fields_for :requests do |builder|
    = render 'request_fields', :f => builder

  %p= link_to_add_fields "Add Request", f, :requests
```

Here is the html i get :

```
onclick="add_fields(this, &amp;quot;requests&amp;quot;, &amp;quot;&amp;lt;div class=\'fields\'&amp;gt;\n  &amp;lt;h1&amp;gt;&amp;lt;label for=\&amp;quot;report_requests_attributes_new_requests_query\&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Query&amp;lt;\/label&amp;gt;&amp;lt;\/h1&amp;gt;\n  &amp;lt;input id=\&amp;quot;report_requests_attributes_new_requests_query\&amp;quot; name=\&amp;quot;report[requests_attributes][new_requests][query]\&amp;quot; size=\&amp;quot;30\&amp;quot; type=\&amp;quot;text\&amp;quot; /&amp;gt;\n  &amp;lt;input id=\&amp;quot;report_requests_attributes_new_requests__destroy\&amp;quot; name=\&amp;quot;report[requests_attributes][new_requests][_destroy]\&amp;quot; type=\&amp;quot;hidden\&amp;quot; value=\&amp;quot;false\&amp;quot; /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;a href=\&amp;quot;#\&amp;quot; onclick=\&amp;quot;remove_fields(this); return false;\&amp;quot;&amp;gt;remove&amp;lt;\/a&amp;gt;\n  &amp;lt;br&amp;gt;\n&amp;lt;\/div&amp;gt;\n&amp;quot;); return false;"
```

I tried to unescape it with CGI.unescapeHTML and i obtain that :

```
"add_fields(this, \"requests\", \"<div class='fields'>\n  <h1><label for=\"requests_query\">Query</label></h1>\n  <input id=\"requests_query\" name=\"requests[query]\" size=\"30\" type=\"text\" />\n  <input id=\"requests__destroy\" name=\"requests[_destroy]\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"false\" /><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"remove_fields(this); return false;\">remove</a>\n  <br>\n</div>\n\"); return false;"
```

All seems correct to me and i don't see where could be the problem. If someone has a idea.

Thanks,

Alain

Comment: Are you using Rails 3? It escapes html by default.

Comment: yes i use rails3. i removed escape_javascript but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: found it. it was the function h which needed to be removed. thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue under rails 3. Removing the H tag doesn't work. Based on your comment about CGI.unescapeHTML, should I be using that or should I try marking the string as html_safe?

Comment: try to use html_safe, it worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the [`h`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ERB/Util.html#method-c-h) function that is escaping the HTML. In `application_helper.rb`:

```rb
link_to_function(name, h("add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")"))
```

should be

```rb
link_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`raw`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-raw) to escape JS properly in Rails 3+:

```erb
<%= raw(@stuff) %>
```

Just make sure what you’re escaping is safe.